# Python image conversion

Tags: python, image

I have a list of images names which are associated with real resources in file system. For example:

```
'image1.png'
'image2.jpg'
'image3.jpeg'
```

I have to conver all of them into `png` with the same name. How can I do that in python?

The ideas are: using PIL or ImageMagic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
from PIL import Image
import os
for filename in filelist:
    basename, ext = os.path.splitext(filename)
    if ext.lower() == ".png":
        continue
    img = Image.open(filename)
    img.save(basename + ".png")
```